# Creating a function to return a core expression using macros

Tags: macros, lambda, scheme

I've been working on some code using R5RS for an assignment to expand certain expressions into core forms of the expression using macros. These are put through a provided eval/apply loop later

```
(define expand (lambda (exp)

(letrec-syntax 
    ((let (syntax-rules ()
        ((_ ((var init) ...) body ...) 
        (`((lambda (var ...) body ...) init ...))))) )
    (exp)) ; sequence to expand
))
(expand (let ((x 2) (y 1)) (+ x y)) )
```

When I run the code like this I get back `;The object 3 is not applicable.` but so it looks like it's actually evaluating exp, but I need to get back a uh...string representation.

If I embed the expression I want expanded into the letrec-syntax body I get back what I actually want. Like so:

```
(define expand (lambda (exp)

(letrec-syntax 
    ((let (syntax-rules ()
        ((_ ((var init) ...) body ...) 
        (`((lambda (var ...) body ...) init ...))))) )
    (let ((x 2) (y 1)) (+ x y))) ; sequence to expand
))
```

I get back ...
`;The object ((lambda (x y) (+ x y)) 2 1) is not applicable` Which looks like what I want to send back to be interpreted.

So my question is how can I rewrite this to take any exp given to expand like in the first example, but return its expanded form like in the second example?

I think the problem has something to do with exp defined by lambda being in the wrong scope in regards to letrec-syntax.  I'm very new to Scheme, and I feel like I'm missing a simple solution here. My best leads so far involve using syntax-case somehow or something about hygienics, but I feel like I've been chasing my tail trying to research those topics so far and I'm not sure they're the right direction.

Thanks for any assistance. :)

Comment: Which Scheme implementation are you using?

Comment: MIT/GNU Scheme based on R5RS from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
(define-syntax expand 
  (syntax-rules (let)
    ((_ (let ((var init) ...) body ...))
     '((lambda (var ...) body ...) init ...))))
```

then

```
> (expand (let ((x 2) (y 1)) (+ x y)))
((lambda (x y) (+ x y)) 2 1)
```

Comment: @uselpha The MIT/GNU Scheme doesn't seem to like syntax-object->datum #' part if I remove that it does give me the expression back if I call expand after, but I get an ill-formed special form error when expand is called later in `(define interpret
      (lambda (exp)
            (exec (expand exp) '()) ))`

Comment: Ok, just installed MIT-Scheme. See my update please.

Comment: Can you explain a little what the value (let) value inside syntax-rules does? Everywhere I see online just uses `(syntax-rules ()
((_)...)`

Comment: This is called a literal, meaning that in this precise position you have to put the word `let` and nothing else. If you omit specifying the literal between parentheses, you can use any word and it will be bound to a variable called `let` which is not what you want.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. The reason I was using letrec-syntax though is because I need to expand other keywords like or, and, case into core expressions also some of which I defined recursively in terms of let. Can you offer any guidance for adding additional syntax-rules to the same expression or do I need to define each separately?